# Apache2: Distinguish between oauth2.0 and Basic auth

Tags: apache2, basic-authentication

This is part of my apache2-conf inside a Location-Tag:

```
                    <If "-n req('Authorization')" >
                            AuthType Basic
                            AuthName static
                            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth/htpasswd
                            Require valid-user
                    </If>
                    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /Mozilla/ || %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /Chrome/">
                            AuthType openid-connect
                            Require claim "groups:humanuser"
                    </ElseIf>
                    <Else>
                            AuthType oauth20
                            Require claim "groups:botuser"
                    </Else>
```

The idea is: If you are visiting with Mozilla/Chrome: Use OIDC (works), else use OAUTH2 (for restclients).

For exactly one legacy client I added the first "if" to enable it to do basic auth - problem here: oauth20 uses the Authorization header as well. So it doesn't work.

Can I check for the value of the Authorization Header ("If it starts with 'Basic'")?